# std::unique_ptr deleter callabe with an argument of type of itself, according to cppreference?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Article on cppreference.com on `std::unique_ptr` writes:

```
Type requirements
-Deleter must be FunctionObject or lvalue reference to a FunctionObject or lvalue reference to function, callable with an argument of
type unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer
```

But what is `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer`?

The Article defines it as follows:

| Member Type | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| pointer | std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer if that type exists, otherwise T*. Must satisfy NullablePointer |

I guess the line `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` means that it is defined as a pointer of the type `Deleter`.

What this tells me is that `Deleter` must be a callable FunctionObject, that takes an argument of type `Deleter*` itself, because `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer` is defined like that.

This makes no sense. So I ask for someone helping me to *make* sense out of it.

Comment: `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` would be what the deleter says it is. It would be weird to designed the deleter such that this is a pointer to `Deleter`.  Rather, it will usually be `T*`, unless the Deleter has some better idea.

Comment: This didn't help clarify things at all.

Comment: The deleter used by default (`std::default_delete<T>`) does not define `::pointer`, which means the function object takes a `T*`. This is the normal case. The standard just says that If you make your own deleter class, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

`Deleter::pointer` would be a nested class or type alias with name `pointer` inside the `Deleter` class. `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type` just makes sure that it is possible to apply the scope resolution operator `::` to the type even if `Deleter` is a reference-to-class type instead of just a class type.

So `std::unique_ptr::pointer` is whatever the `Deleter` class type chooses it to be or `T*` by default if it doesn't have a `pointer` member.

In theory it *could* be a pointer to `Deleter` itself, but that logically doesn't seem to make much sense. I can't really image why a deleter would choose `pointer` that way.

In most cases you wouldn't need to have `Deleter` specify `pointer` at all. The default `T*` is fine for normal use cases. But you might want to use so-called *fancy pointers* which carry e.g. additional metadata or be in other ways different from native pointers, in which case `Deleter` would need to specify `pointer` to the fancy pointer type. For example [`boost::interprocess::offset_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) is such a fancy pointer type used to allow sharing pointers in memory shared between processes where each process maps the memory region to a different offset. Here the default `T*` wouldn't work, because the value of the pointer would be correct in only one of the processes.